# Will a permanent redirecting domain appear in Google search results?

Tags: domains, google-search, redirects, search-results

I have a domain A which will permanently redirect to domain B. May I know if there is a chance domain A will appear from Google search results? Or it will not appear at all?

In this case, how do I let domain A appear in Google search results and have a redirect to domain B?

Comment: *Will a permanent redirecting domain appear in Google search results?* No. *How do I let domain A appear in Google search results and have a redirect to domain B?* You can't.

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks for the answers. Do you think any of the 2 options will work instead? 1) Make a static page for domain A and automatically redirect to domain B in 5 seconds after page loads. 2) Make a static page for domain A and have a link to domain B. Will domain A in any of options appears in Google search results page?

Comment: @Norman If you use a permanent redirect like a `301` issued from a web server or script, the origin URL from domain A will eventually be replaced by the target URL from domain B. If you still want domain A to appear, you could do a meta refresh for option 1, which would result in the target URL's title and description appearing, but the URL that would be indexed would be the origin's URL. This is generally not advisable because of various issues (like duplicate content, refreshes that don't work for certain browsers, etc...).  Option 2 is a safe choice, but if it contains the same content...

Comment: use a [canonical link element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) to let Google know you prefer that the URL from domain A be indexed instead of domain B.

Comment: The question is, What is it you are trying to achieve? This is a roundabout question that avoids giving away the true intent. What is it you want to achieve? Why is it so important to have domain a and domain b appear in the SERPs and yet be tied together? Are you thinking that two domains will return more search users? If that is what you are thinking, then unless the two sites have real content, there cannot be an advantage. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc The ideal of having domain A to redirect to domain B is because my client would like those who search for domain A to be directed to domain B. I understand that domain B could also use the keywords for domain A so that it will also appear in the search results page, however the client would just like to play safe for now since domain B is not hitting high in the search results. I think option 2 would be a better choice, just a simple static page to inform user that they can get more content from domain B.

Comment: I am afraid your customer is not understanding how search works. A domain with a single page will do nothing. As well using a 301 from one to the other will do nothing. Infact, having more than one domain per site does absolutely nothing. You are far better off dropping one domain or the other and focusing on making one site perform. Keep in mind that search is not about keywords. That is an SEO industry myth to get your money or attention. The original Google research paper actually states that term match search returns poor results and proposes using semantics for better results.

Answer (score 3):

There will be a transition from Google showing Domain A to Domain B. Depending how large and how crawlable your site is, it can take days or even weeks for the transition to be complete.

The end result though will be that only Domain B will be left in the index since Domain A permanently redirects to Domain B. There is no point Google showing Domain A since it effectively  has no content and so search results will only show Domain B.

Google will only keep a redirecting page in the index if it is a temporary redirect, returning 302 instead of 301. That will also slow down your users since the redirect will not be cached.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't index pages from redirecting domains.   However, Google does the right thing when somebody searches for the domain that redirects.  It shows show search results from the target domain.   Google uses redirecting domains as a major factor in deciding if a query deserves "do you mean" treatment.

Here is a fictional example that illustrates a misspelling  redirecting to `example.com`.   I created this from one of my own redirecting domains, but anonymized it by using the example domain.  In my case the alternate domain has a `301 permanent` redirect to my main domain.  For my sites, this works whether the search includes the `.com` or just the alternate brand name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If Domain A has organic search presence then it will appear in Google Search for some. If you have done proper redirection on domain B (Including all pages) and does not generate any 404 error on domain B then after sometime domain A organic search result will be transferred to domain B.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by organic search presence? Domain A itself do not have a web page and will only serve as a redirection purpose. Will it still appear in Google search results page?

Comment: Okay, In this condition Domain A will not appear in the google search.

Answer (score 0):

Google will still reindex old domain (DOMAIN A) if it doesn't refreshes its database. There will be a dance on your rankings but as long as a proper 301 redirect is applied, it should be back on track. Also, submit new redirected URL (DOMAIN B) to Google's search index for faster indexation (fetch as Google in the Google Search Console).